# log_reuse_wait_desc showing LOG_BACKUP even I am taking Full(or Transactional Log) Backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database on production. Recovery model is Full. The problem is that the database log size is keep growing. There is no long running transactions. Reading forums I have found that taking log backup will fix this issue. I have taken full and Transactional Log Backup. But when I run,

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc, log_reuse_wait FROM sys.databases
```

The result is,

```
  LOG_BACKUP    2
```

Why is this happening? Should I shrink the databse?

Comment: `I have taken Transactional Log Backup`: the server says you didn't. I trust the server message more than I trust you.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, I have done right click on db > backup > transaction log. Anything else I need to.

Comment: +1 for Remus. What happens if you temporarily switch to simple recovery?

Comment: @dean, I have not switched to simple recovery. I have taken the log backup. I am not expert but Paul Randal says that if you take backup then log will be clear, http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/sqlserver-logging

Comment: Both Remus and myself agree with Paul. I'm just suggesting that you switch to simple and then check the log_reuse_wait_desc.

Comment: @dean, the db is in production. I am fearing to making it simple whihc might affect my production db.

Comment: It won't currupt the data. Make a full backup if you're worried (but you did that already, right?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reading forums I have found that taking log backup will fix this issue

Depends a lot on what is the 'issue'. Log backup will *free* the log (make space available inside the LDF file), but will not *shrink* the log (make the LDF file smaller). Read [How to shrink the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/).

This should not be a just-in-time rush to fix. You **must** have a recovery plan in action, which includes a proper backup plan, running automated on a schedule. Is much better to set the recovery to SIMPLE rather than mess with manual log backups.

Comment: Shrink. Lot of peoples against it. http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Comment: that would be *data* shrink with all the folk up in arms against it. Log shrink is mostly harmless, but should not be abused.

Comment: Making Recovery Level to Simple have any drawbacks?

Comment: It depends on what your goals are. Why **is** the recovery FULL now? Who set it and why?

Comment: Set it to SIMPLE, no real harm now. Then read more about recovery goals, go over [Choosing the Recovery Model for a Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175987(v=sql.105).aspx), figure out a proper plan, implement a backup and maintenance plan. as part of implementing said plan, you'll change to the desired *business requirements driven* recovery mode.